# Is the OS X Lion clean installation less stable than the upgrade install?

Tags: macos

I upgraded to OS X Lion yesterday, everything went fine and I used it for the day without crashes or problems. In the evening, I decided to burn myself a DVD from the installer, and I did a clean install. Am I the only one to notice that the OS X Lion clean install is buggier than the upgrade? Why is that?

Examples of "buggier":

- I wasn't able to finish the initial user account set up. At the moment of taking a picture of myself for my account, I got away from my computer 10 minutes, it seemed to go on sleep, and it never woke up.
- After that, on the login screen, I entered my pwd, pressed ok, and the wait cursor showed up. I let it spin for 10 minutes, then got tired of it and restarted the computer.
- Finally, this morning, after my computer woke from sleep mode, the mail full screen application froze on an administrator login screen.

--EDIT--

After a couple of weeks of using Lion, everything goes smoothly. The issues I had have gone away automatically.

Comment: It would be great to elaborate on what makes you feel it is buggy. You might have something worth picking apart, but without sharing more it's hard to be concrete.

Comment: Define "buggier". I wrote the image from the installer to a USB stick and made a clean install using that. Worked very smoothly and without any problems.

Comment: I added examples

Comment: Seeing your examples there, you don't seem to have any problems with the installation process itself, but rather with the system post-install. This can't be related to the way you've installed Lion, because the installer-app uses the same image that you have burned to DVD. Are you sure that your hardware is ok? Sounds like a faulty RAM stick to me.

Comment: What is strange is that I was using GM version(same build as the one released yesterday) since a week, with no crashes. Anyways, I'll try to make it crash again tonight and if it does I'll reinstall everything again... I was hoping someone here had the same problems!

Comment: Yes, I have noticed this. I have a handful of music applications that installed and launched just fine on Lion when I upgraded from Snow Leopard. After doing a clean install of Lion, however, those same apps crash when launched. Don't know what to think of that, but thought I'd contribute this bit of info anyway.

Comment: A clean install requires both (1) erasure of the volume to which the system will be installed, and (2) neither restoring nor migrating. At the time of instability, did  your machine fulfil both criteria?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have it on good authority that all Lion installs are a standard install followed by a migration of data (local, remote or Time Machine based) so as long as you are following the official steps, having less to migrate will only be more buggy if you add that "bad data" once the install has finished.

If the software installed poorly, the same software should have the same bugs boot after boot after boot. Can you reproduce any of these issues? It sure sounds like a hardware (RAM or HDD) issue instead of some bug in the installer. The only way to know is to clean install Snow Leopard or dig into the specifics. I don't think enough people have run the installer in the DVD manner you mentioned for any "word on the street reports" to be useful.

Sorry I don't have a better idea other than going through the usual issue isolation steps.

- [Isolating issues in Mac OS X](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS1388)
- [Mac OS X: How to troubleshoot a software issue](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1199)

Answer (score 3):

The DVD install is not an official, sanctioned by Apple, way to install the OS. So it's not *that* surprising that thing don't go as smoothly.

Or maybe it's just bad luck when burning or installing the OS. So you can try to install it once again, even burning another DVD to see if that was the problem.

If you want to do a clean install, there will be official USB key in August. But they'll cost more that two times the price of Lion on the Mac App Store